# How can I access to a database on OpenShift?

Tags: php, database, openshift-online-2

I created an application on OpenShift, everything is working and there are no problems. I now need to attach the database that is on OpenShift with my desktop application developed in C #. The desktop application only needs to read the data that we have within the database tables and nothing else. On the net I found no tutorial related to OpenShift and so I ask here if anyone has had experience in this regard.

The connection to the application of OpenShift is performative as a key complementary and do not know if this can create problems. Can someone show me a simple example?

I know does not provide aid of this kind, but I just want to figure out how to connect my desktop application to the online database hosted on OpenShift and nothing else, how could I do?

```
string connStr = @"Server=test-lound.rhcloud.com;Port=8000;Database=test;Uid=adminxxJ;Pwd=FxxxBdL;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
            conn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection successfull !");

            conn.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Eccezione =>  " + ex.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
```

on conn.Open() is returned this exception:

> Eccezione =>  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
>      in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
>      in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
>      in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
>      in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
>      in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
>      in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
>      in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
>      in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()

Comment: Create an API, and then use it.

Comment: There is no way to made a connection without external resource in openshift?

Comment: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/203263674-What-external-ports-are-available-on-OpenShift-

Comment: Ok I've write a code for made a connection, see my updated anwer, anyway I've an exception on this code, could you help me to solve?